# Listener service for soap request in web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to make a Web API to receive a request from External SOAP service.

**Working of SOAP Service:** When i send a request to External service i also provide a callback url on which service is going to send me a response.

I want to do it in Asp.net Core WebAPI. This is what i've done.

I have created a WebAPI controller to get the response.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class RewardsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/B2CListener")]
    public ActionResult GetData(string document)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When that external service send me the response i got error (extracted from Logging) that 405 Method not allowed. My Application can get the response from External Service but unable to get it in my service due to method not allowed. I tried `HttpPost`,`HttpGet`,`HttpPut` but nothing works. Any help can be appreciated.

**Logging:** This is what logging captured.

**Request**

```
http 10.117.8.132:801/api/B2CListener/  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/result"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Result><ResultParameters><ResultParameter><Key>FailedReason</Key><Value>Failed to match a reason type because the Identity Subtype factor of the credit party does not match.</Value></ResultParameter></ResultParameters><ResultCode>2005</ResultCode><ResultType>0</ResultType><OriginatorConversationID>SX20130129210023</OriginatorConversationID><ResultDesc>Can not match reason type.</ResultDesc><TransactionID>000000000000</TransactionID><ConversationID>AG_20130AAS2</ConversationID></Result>]]></res:ResultMsg></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
405:
```

I have used RequestResponse Logging using `middleware`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of Error 405 is due to the fact that SOAP request is always a `HttpPost` and i have mistakenly added the `[Authorize]` tag on controller due to which the request gets failed.

**Updated Code**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RewardsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/B2CListener")]
    public void GetData()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Do something
            }
        }
}
```